# Organisations that run projects as a voluntary service

Tags: data-request

Is there any list of organisations that run projects as voluntary service — 
a list of organisations that offer opportunities to find projects that volunteers might be interested in?

See for example two very good lists in Europe:

- http://europa.eu/youth/evs_database with more than 4000 results
- http://europa.eu/youth/vp/opportunity_list

Especially I am interested in

- South America
- North America
- Africa
- Asia